# Upgrade got stuck. How can I fix this?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 16.04

Since other posts suggest this, I should mention that I cannot run `dpkg --configure -a`, even after killing the process.

In any case, the Distribution Upgrade window blacked out, and when I try to close it, I get the following message... after which I still can't close it.

> **Application ubuntu-release-upgrader is not responding**
>   You tried to close window "Distribution Upgrade" from application "ubuntu-release-upgrader" (Process Id: 2414) but the application is
>   not responding.
>
> Do you want to terminate this application?
>
> **Warning:** Terminating the application will close all of its child windows. Any unsaved data will be lost.

I tried killing the process from the command line `kill -9 2414`, I'm not sure it did.  Then I ran `dpkg --configure -a` and I got that it's been used by another process.

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

I've seen other posts where they just remove the look.  Is this safe to do?
How should I proceed to contain the damage?

Comment: This seems an old question, anyway, you were able to check if package installer still running using `ps aux | grep apt` . If it is killed , you may remove  the lock files then start over the upgrade.